# Objective matlab - returning multiple class properties with its one function

Tags: class, matlab

I'm trying to return more than one property of the class with its single function:

```
classdef myClass

    properties
        a
        b
        c
    end

    methods

        % ...

        function P = returnABC(obj)
            P = [obj.a obj.b obj.c];
        end

    end
```

I know it's not correct but it represents what I' m trying to achieve. May I kindly ask you to help me fix it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about why your current implementation is not giving the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that the same way you do it using normal functions:

```
classdef myClass

    properties
        a
        b
        c
    end

    methods

        % ...

        function [a, b, c] = returnABC(obj)
            a = obj.a;
            b = obj.b;
            c = obj.c;
        end

    end
```

Comment: I think you'll have to use different variable names, since a, b, and c are already property names. I'm not 100% on that though.

Comment: @jerad: As far as I know MATLAB has no implicit `this` object (see http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/digest/2008/sept/matlab-objects.html), which requires us to write `obj.property` whenever we want to access a certain property. On the contrary this would mean `a, b, c` do not have the meaning as a property name on their own and thus could be used elsewhere. But I am not entirely certain on this.

Comment: @jerad: no, you don't, but you will get an underline for it that warns you that you may get confused with variables and properties having the same names.

Comment: @Jonas: Your right, messed up with this one. Here it comes: http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/digest/2008/sept/matlab-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of each property they may not be concatenable.
Better would be to use a cell as output.

```
function [c]=getall(obj)
    p=properties(obj);      
    for i=1:length(p),
        c{i}=get(obj,p{i});
    end
end
```

Note the use of the properties method, to make it generic: no need to update this method if you change/rename the properties!